# How to make bounds of document unlimited?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to transform a selection in my image to very high size in photoshop but sometimes i get following error:

[image]

How can i fix this error?
How to make bounds of document unlimited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to have unlimited bounds.

Photoshop has a [file limit](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/image-size-resolution.html#:%7E:text=Photoshop%20supports%20maximum%20pixel%20dimension,resolution%20available%20to%20an%20image.) of **300,000x300,000 pixels** and **4GB** for every file.

If you are hitting these limitations often, you should reevaluate your workflow.